# What is wrong with this query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I run [this SEDE query by Sam Saffron](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/946/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day):

```sql
set nocount on

DECLARE @endDate date
SELECT @endDate = max(CreationDate) from Posts

set nocount off

SELECT TOP 50
    Id AS [User Link], Reputation, Days,
    Reputation/Days AS RepPerDays
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CONVERT(int, @endDate - CreationDate) as Days
    FROM Users
) AS UsersAugmented
WHERE
    Reputation > 5000
ORDER BY
    RepPerDays DESC
```

it returns an error about the data types:

```
The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the subtract operator.
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type for the `endDate` was wrong; [changing it to `datetime` makes the query work](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/203465/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day).

My guess is that an earlier version of SQL Server was more tolerant of using a `date` where a `datetime` is required.

Congrats, for Mi Yodea you are ranked first!

Comment: Thanks - how do I update the query to not use the date you created it, but rather the current date, as the end date?

Comment: It doesn't. It uses the most recent post date every time you run it. Do take into account the data is not live, it is updated once a week, so the `max(CreationDate)` is up to a week old.

Comment: I guess I need to be more patient :)